# can't access my nodejs express site through lan

Tags: node.js, linux, express, ubuntu

I installed on my new laptop ubuntu 18.4.01.
I develop a site with node and express, on my old laptop who runs windows 10, when I wrote the ip address (lan) the site showed up immediately, while on the new ubuntu pc I can see the request handled as expected but it loading forever and doesn't show up. 
p.s I disabled the firewall. when using localhost the site is loaded as expected.

my express code:

```
import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import https from 'https';
import fs from 'fs';
import pagesRouter from './pages/pagesRouter';
import apiRouter from './api/api_router';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

//Encryption assests
const privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('./app/server/encryption/localhost.key', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('./app/server/encryption/localhost.crt', 'utf8');
const credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

const app = express();

const assets = express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../'));

app.use(cors());
app.use(assets);

//Database connection
const uri = process.env.DB_CONNECTION_STRING;
mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true});

//Every route with api
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
//Every route that doesn't have api
app.get(/^((?!api).)*$/, pagesRouter);

//https connection
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials,app, () => {
    console.log('Listening HTTPs')
  });  
httpsServer.listen(8443);

export default app;
```

The windows and linux machines run the same code.
In other lan network it worked!!

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: edited my question

Comment: Can you give it a try using http server in case if you are using self-signed certificates?

Comment: Thank you for your time, i tried using http server, i notice that i have access to the static files through the same url and path...